# A simple sprite sheet animation in Cocos2d-JS

Tags: animation, sprite-sheet, cocos2d-js

Based on the helloworld-example and the cocos-2d-x docs (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Sprite_Sheet_Animation) I tried to make a simple sprite sheet animation. Here is the code:

```
this.mostafa = cc.Sprite.create(res.Mostafa_png);        
this.mostafa.attr({
    x: size.width / 3,
    y: size.height / 3,
    scale: 0.2,
    rotation: 180
});
this.addChild(this.mostafa, 0);
var rotate = cc.RotateTo.create(2, 0);

cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.Mostafa_plist);

var animFrames = [];
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    str = "mosquito_fly" + (i < 10 ? ("0" + i) : i) + ".png";
    var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
    animFrames.push(frame);
}
var animation = cc.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.04);
var animate   = cc.Animate.create(animation); 

this.mostafa.runAction(animate);  // shows nothing
//this.mostafa.runAction(rotate);   // shows turning sprite
```

It doesn't show anything. But if I put in the last line and put out the second last, then it shows a rotating sprite. (the sprite frame cache is loaded correctly)

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was twofold. First there has to be a texture defined for the animation, and second, if it should be a continous animation, than the animFrames have to of type animationFrame. The working code is as follows (put in the ctor function of the helloworld example):

```
// Create sprite and set attributes
    this.mostafa = cc.Sprite.create(res.Mostafa_single_png);        
    this.mostafa.attr({
        x: size.width / 3,
        y: size.height / 3,
        scale: 0.5,
        rotation: 0
    });
    this.addChild(this.mostafa, 0);

// Load sprite frames to frame cache, add texture node
    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.Mostafa_plist);
    var mostafaTexture = cc.textureCache.addImage(res.Mostafa_png),
        mostafaImages  = cc.SpriteBatchNode.create(mostafaTexture);
    this.addChild(mostafaImages);

    var animFrames = [];
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        str = "mosquito_fly" + (i < 10 ? ("0" + i) : i) + ".png";
        var spriteFrame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
        var animFrame = new cc.AnimationFrame();
            animFrame.initWithSpriteFrame(spriteFrame, 1, null);
        animFrames.push(animFrame);
    }
    var animation = cc.Animation.create(animFrames, 0.08, 100);
    var animate   = cc.Animate.create(animation); 

    this.mostafa.runAction(animate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
junk = this;
cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames("res/e.plist");
spriteSheet = new cc.SpriteBatchNode("res/e.png");
junk.addChild(spriteSheet,15);

var animFrames = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
    var str = "e/e"+i+".png";
    var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
    animFrames.push(frame);
}
var animation = new cc.Animation(animFrames, 0.1);
runningAction =  new cc.RepeatForever(new cc.Animate(animation));

mask = new cc.Sprite("#e/e1.png");
mask.attr({
    x: 400,
    y:105,
    anchorX: 0.5,
    anchorY: 0.5,
    scale:0.5
});
spriteSheet.addChild(mask,25);
mask.runAction(runningAction)
```